# VS Code no log into Debug Console when is verbose

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How can I make VS Code to write in ***Debug Console*** when I use

```
winston.log('verbose', ...messages);
```

Actually I can get log only if I use a straight ***console.log***

Comment: Have u installed Winston? Have u include Winston in the file?

Comment: I am seeing the message getting logged. However it's not in the usual white color which we expect.

Comment: @PrashantTapase

`-- winston@2.4.4
  +-- async@1.0.0
  +-- colors@1.0.3
  +-- cycle@1.0.3
  +-- eyes@0.1.8
  +-- isstream@0.1.2
  `-- stack-trace@0.0.10

Comment: @klvenky nothing for me

Comment: can u provide complete details/code? winston file code? how did u include etc. Maybe this will help u https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-winston-to-log-node-js-applications